# Kuntrus Midor L'Dor

Tags: jewish-books, estates-inheritance

Does anyone know where I can obtain a copy of the book Kuntrus Midor L'Dor by Rabbi Feivel Cohen?  It has been out of print for some time now.

Comment: What is the topic of the book?

Comment: Mark Caren, welcome to Mi Yodeya. [Editing into the question](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/22538/edit) any information you know about the book (such as its subject matter, the date it was published, its genre, where it was published, or the like) may help others help you locate the book. Please also consider [registering](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your account, which will [give you access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) to more of the site's features.

Comment: It's a guide to writing a will in accordance with halachah.

Answer (score 2):

[Z. Berman](http://zbermanbooks.com/product-40517.html) has it in stock for $20.

You can also use [WorldCat](http://www.worldcat.org/title/kuntres-mi-dor-le-dor-bo-yitbaer-derekh-nakhon-bi-khetivat-tsavaah-she-yehe-be-hetem-le-dine-ha-torah-ve-gam-yitbaaru-bo-od-dinim-ha-nogim-le-hiluk-izvono-shel-ha-adam/oclc/36052865&referer=brief_results) to find a list of libraries near you that own this title.

Comment: Are you sure there is a separate English version? It's been many years since I last saw it, but if memory serves correctly, there is some English content (document text for sure, but maybe more) in the Hebrew sefer.

Comment: Just checked with the store.  Unfortunately,  the volume for sale does not comtain english.

Comment: @MarkCaren You might find this article interesting: http://www.bethdin.org/docs/PDF14-Halachic_Will_Materials.pdf